Vault cannot upload oidc discovery
I wanto to get secret Vault from my Gitlab CI, but I need before to enable jwt auth.
So I follow this documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/#configure-your-vault-server
vault auth enable jwt
vault write auth/jwt/config oidc_discovery_url="https://gitlab.example.com" oidc_client_id="xxx" oidc_client_secret="yyy" bound_issier="https://gitlab.example.com"

Error writing data to auth/jwt/config: Error making API request.


URL: PUT https://vault.example.com/v1/auth/jwt/config
Code: 400. Errors:

* error checking oidc discovery URL

But when , I want to write a config on jwt, I get 400 errors.
So, I try to enable jwt, on my gitlab CI, I follow this documentation to enable vault integration  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/vault.html
Redirect URI on my gitlab.example.com
https://localhost:8250/oidc/callback
https://vault.example.com/ui/vault/auth/oidc/oidc/callback

But I stil get this error 400, so how I could succeded this command please
vault write auth/jwt/config oidc_discovery_url="https://gitlab.example.com" oidc_client_id="xxx" oidc_client_secret="yyy" bound_issier="https://gitlab.example.com"


any help, please

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I add more information on my question
